# Workaround for DateTime::diff() in PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, datetime

I currently have a script to calculate the difference between two dates, in days:

```
$now      = new DateTime();
$birthday = new DateTime('1973-04-18 09:48:00');
$interval = $now->diff($birthday);
echo $interval->format('%a days');
```

However, I keep on getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in /home/test/public_html/age.php on line 4

I found out that this code is only supposed to work with PHP version 5.3, however, is there a workaround for 5.2.17?

Comment: You shouldn't use that old php versions

Comment: See this question. Some of the answers have the code you can use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: There is always the `$days = ($now->getTimestamp() - $birthday->getTimestamp()) / (24*3600)`

Comment: ring0 getTimestamp() is also only available in PHP 5.3, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can use for DateTime::diff() for PHP 5.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033224/what-can-use-for-datetimediff-for-php-5-2)

Comment: @Nox there are those of us who have no control over what version of PHP is being used...