# Return array of date strings for a date range in php 5.2

Tags: php, date

I have this code

```
<?php
function getDatesBetween2Dates($startTime, $endTime) {
  $day = 86400;
  $format = 'd-m-Y';
  $startTime = strtotime($startTime);
  $endTime = strtotime($endTime);
  $numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day) + 1;
  $days = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < $numDays; $i++) {
      $days[] = date($format, ($startTime + ($i * $day)));
  }

  return $days;
}

$days = getDatesBetween2Dates(
  date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$start")),
  date('d-m-Y',strtotime("$end"))
);

foreach ($days as $key => $value) {
  // ...
}
```

this then goes on to search a database and display results based on a date return. I did not write this code and have no idea where i had it from.

The problem is that is is returning two 2nd november 2014??? Its messing every thing up.
Any help would be awesome. I shall try and share a page link. ( the page holds personal info)

http://djwservices.co.uk/invoices/calendar.php

As a side question if anyone can get the expand/shrink to work on onclick that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance
Daz

Comment: Why do people have this mistaken belief that every day is 86400 seconds long?

Comment: [link](http://djwservices.co.uk/invoices/calendar.php) the page in question.

Comment: I realise not all days have 86400 seconds or in fact no day is 24 hours long butim still stuck!

Comment: `d-m-Y` is a pretty ugly format to be using as your datestrings. And why are you doing string->date->string like a drunk sailor? Going to string should be the LAST thing you do before displaying to a human. Keep things as a normal timestamp within PHP to save you multiple roundtrips through ambiguous string formats.

Comment: As i said i didnt write this and i work under the theory.. if it aint broke, dont break it!. This worked up until 2nd November 2014. Its now broke and i cant fix it?

Comment: I was thinking of two very specific dates each year, when countries that have daylight savings have fewer and greater than 24 hrs in a day respectively

Comment: Coincidentally, in the United states, that date with 25 hours happens to fall on the very date that appears twice in your list

Comment: If you can update to php 5.3 you can use the built in functions to avoid these sort of issues. Although it would be great to update to 5.6 if you don't have compatibility problems (which, honestly, you probably will with an old code base). The newer functions make problems like this much easier to deal with.

Comment: Ok i have tried both solutions and have to go now so will try more later. Thinking about seconds in the day i tried upping the second count of my original script from 86400 to 87000 and it seems to have done the trick for now. Kind of a duct tape solution ;)

Comment: Of course, it may well break again on 8th Mar 2015, but hopefully you'll have implemented a sensible fix by then

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP 5.5 Generators, you could do something like:

```
function period($begin, $interval, $end) {
    while ($begin <= $end) {
        yield $begin;
        $begin->add($interval);
    }
}

$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');

$begin = new \DateTime( '2014-11-01' );
$end = new \DateTime( '2014-11-30' );

foreach (period($begin, $interval, $end) as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format( "Y-m-d" ), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Tried this too....
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /hermes/waloraweb034/b1699/moo.myeventpicturescouk/djw/invoices/test.php on line 12

Comment: As I said, this solution requires PHP >= 5.5

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier using the function, date_diff. From the manual:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Here is a modified version for if you don't yet have php 5.3:

```
function getDatesBetween2Dates($startTime, $endTime) {
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($startTime);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($endTime);
    $interval = round(($datetime2->format('U') - $datetime1->format('U')) / (60*60*24));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $interval; $i++) {
       $dateTemp = $datetime1;
       $str = "+" . $i . " day";
       $dateTemp = $dateTemp->modify($str);
       $days[] = $dateTemp->format('d-m-Y');
    }

   return $days;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it getting this error   
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in /hermes/waloraweb034/b1699/moo.myeventpicturescouk/djw/invoices/test.php on line 12

Comment: Ah, you are not on php 5.3 then. Referencing this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033224/what-can-use-for-datetimediff-for-php-5-2

Comment: I added a php 5.2 friendly version.

Comment: Also updated it to return it in the format you wanted.

Comment: Also updated the for loop so it now includes the start date in the return values and does not include the end date (so it is more like the original)

Comment: Still no joy

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in /hermes/waloraweb034/b1699/moo.myeventpicturescouk/djw/invoices/test.php on line 12

thats this line
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

Comment: Ok. I deleted the version that only works in php5.3+ try this version :)

Comment: Im now getting a +2days on a test page but all kinds of strange things on my calendar page

Comment: It sounds like it's doing something funny with the string parsing. I made an update to get around that.

Comment: Did that work? It's working for me on a test machine.

Comment: lasty try it didnt work, i will try again tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far. As a quick fix i increased my seconds in a day which has given me some time at least.