# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

When my code is moved from local server to live server it shows an error like this :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()

Code:

```
<?php      
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
  $sFinalDate   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sDate));
  $sNow         = new DateTime();
  $iRemain      = new DateTime( $sFinalDate.$sTime);
  $iInterval    = $iRemain->diff($sNow);
  $sTimeCounter = $iInterval->format("%h: %i :%s ");
  $sCalculate   = $iInterval->format("%a:%h:%i");
?>
```

Comment: My local server is : 4.5.5.1 @PaulCrovella

Comment: And Live Version information: 4.3.8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033224/what-can-use-for-datetimediff-for-php-5-2 refer this

Comment: @SJP you really, *really* should be looking to update to PHP 5.3 (or better) as soon as practically possible. PHP4 had an [end of life announcement](http://php.net/archive/2007.php) on the 13th July 2007. That was ***NINE YEARS AGO***

Answer (score 2):

> Though I found a number of people who ran into the issue of 5.2 and
>   lower not supporting this function, I was unable to find any solid
>   examples to get around it. Therefore I hope this can help some others:

```
<?php 
function get_timespan_string($older, $newer) { 
  $Y1 = $older->format('Y'); 
  $Y2 = $newer->format('Y'); 
  $Y = $Y2 - $Y1; 

  $m1 = $older->format('m'); 
  $m2 = $newer->format('m'); 
  $m = $m2 - $m1; 

  $d1 = $older->format('d'); 
  $d2 = $newer->format('d'); 
  $d = $d2 - $d1; 

  $H1 = $older->format('H'); 
  $H2 = $newer->format('H'); 
  $H = $H2 - $H1; 

  $i1 = $older->format('i'); 
  $i2 = $newer->format('i'); 
  $i = $i2 - $i1; 

  $s1 = $older->format('s'); 
  $s2 = $newer->format('s'); 
  $s = $s2 - $s1; 

  if($s < 0) { 
    $i = $i -1; 
    $s = $s + 60; 
  } 
  if($i < 0) { 
    $H = $H - 1; 
    $i = $i + 60; 
  } 
  if($H < 0) { 
    $d = $d - 1; 
    $H = $H + 24; 
  } 
  if($d < 0) { 
    $m = $m - 1; 
    $d = $d + get_days_for_previous_month($m2, $Y2); 
  } 
  if($m < 0) { 
    $Y = $Y - 1; 
    $m = $m + 12; 
  } 
  $timespan_string = create_timespan_string($Y, $m, $d, $H, $i, $s); 
  return $timespan_string; 
} 

function get_days_for_previous_month($current_month, $current_year) { 
  $previous_month = $current_month - 1; 
  if($current_month == 1) { 
    $current_year = $current_year - 1; //going from January to previous December 
    $previous_month = 12; 
  } 
  if($previous_month == 11 || $previous_month == 9 || $previous_month == 6 || $previous_month == 4) { 
    return 30; 
  } 
  else if($previous_month == 2) { 
    if(($current_year % 4) == 0) { //remainder 0 for leap years 
      return 29; 
    } 
    else { 
      return 28; 
    } 
  } 
  else { 
    return 31; 
  } 
} 

function create_timespan_string($Y, $m, $d, $H, $i, $s) 
{ 
  $timespan_string = ''; 
  $found_first_diff = false; 
  if($Y >= 1) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($Y, 'year').' '; 
  } 
  if($m >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($m, 'month').' '; 
  } 
  if($d >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($d, 'day').' '; 
  } 
  if($H >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($H, 'hour').' '; 
  } 
  if($i >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($i, 'minute').' '; 
  } 
  if($found_first_diff) { 
    $timespan_string .= 'and '; 
  } 
  $timespan_string .= pluralize($s, 'second'); 
  return $timespan_string; 
} 

function pluralize( $count, $text ) 
{ 
  return $count . ( ( $count == 1 ) ? ( " $text" ) : ( " ${text}s" ) ); 
} 
?>
```

source http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php
if you using php 5.3 then there would be another issue
working above example on php>=5.3